# display instance ids based on instance tags aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

need instance ids if particular tag['key'] is not tagged
i am trying to list instance ids based on some tags 
for ex :: if tag:name=env and value = 'Not tagged'(like it filters in console) ()

```
import boto3
client=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
filters=[{'Name':'env', 'Values':['Not tagges']}]
response=client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your filters should be as follows:

```
filters = 
  [{
    'Name':'tag:env', 
    'Values': ['not tagged']
  }]

response=client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

and then for example you can further filter and select only instance IDs + Hypervisor:

```
for r in response['Reservations']:
    for i in r['Instances']:
        print(i['InstanceId'], i['Hypervisor'])
```

Comment: Will try that but after that how do I filter all instance iss which are matching filter ?

Comment: below is my code it is returning empty response 
client=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
filters=[{'Name':'tag:env', 'Values':['not tagged']}]
response=client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
#print(response)
for res in response['Reservations']:
    for inst in res['Instances']:
 print(inst['InstanceId'])

Answer (score 0):

Parameters
Filters (list) --
The filters.

tag-key - The key of a tag assigned to the resource.
 
Use this filter to find all resources that have a tag with a specific key, regardless of the tag value.

if the problem still presists...
Buzz me...
r0ck

Comment: client=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
filters=[{'Name':'tag:env', 'Values':['not tagged']}]
response=client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
#print(response)
for res in response['Reservations']:
    for inst in res['Instances']:
 print(inst['InstanceId'])